# ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gifski’

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I'd like to use the `gganimate` package in R, but it requires `gifski` which is failing.

```
* installing *source* package ‘gifski’ ...
** package ‘gifski’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
------------------ RUST COMPILER NOT FOUND --------------------

Cargo was not found on the PATH. Please install cargo / rustc:

 - yum install cargo         (Fedora/CentOS)
 - apt-get install cargo     (Debian/Ubuntu)
 - brew install rustc        (MacOS)

Alternatively install Rust from: <https://www.rust-lang.org>

---------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gifski’
* removing ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/gifski’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gifski’ had non-zero exit status
```

It says I need to install Rust, but I've done that. I ran these commands and then rebooted.

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

Here is my instance information.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03
```

Comment: Did you try `source $HOME/.cargo/env` after install?

Comment: Is `cargo` in `$PATH` variable? check with `which cargo`